# How to properly pass event handlers as props into typescript react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass this handleSubmit event handler and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. The function works fine if I use an anonymous function on the child component. The compiler doesn't throw any errors and I've used the typings from when you highlight the "onSubmit" prop on VS Code.

**This is the parent component.**

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const authToken = () => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);

  const handleSubmit = ((e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(authToken()));
    setAuth(true);
    console.log('submit works');
  });


  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} auth={auth} component={Login} />
        <Route path="/userlist" component={UserList} />
        <Route path="/editscreen" component={EditScreen} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**And the Child Component**

```
interface Props {
  handleSubmit: ((e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void);
  auth: boolean;
}

const Login: React.FC<Props> = ({ handleSubmit, auth }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          required
        ></input>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          required
        ></input>
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the handler as a prop for the "Login" component, not as a prop for "Route"  component.

Try this:

```
<Route path="/" exact={true} render={(props) => <Login {...props} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} auth={auth} />} />
```

or:

```
<Route path="/" exact={true} component={() => <Login handleSubmit={handleSubmit} auth={auth} />} />
```

But the last one is not recommended for using due to perfomance reasons.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component

Answer (score 0):

Passing arbitrary props on `<Route>` will not filter down to the rendered component like that. You probably want to pass in the Component as a child with all the props you want.

Instead of:

```
<Route
  path="/"
  exact={true}
  handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
  auth={auth}
  component={Login}
/>
```

Try:

```
<Route path="/" exact={true}>
  <Login handleSubmit={handleSubmit} auth={auth} />
</Route>
```

This way it's very clear what's a prop of the route, and what's a prop of the component rendered by that route.